# Get grid Node's Neighbors

Tags: python, matrix, pygame, grid

I'm doing a pathfinding visualizer and I need to get nodes' neighbors in order to perform on them the algorithm I want to make an adjacency list and then just update colors but the problem is when I try to make a dictionary with a node's row and column and its neighbors it outputs a wrong thing, and I will explain what I mean by that and why the problem is happening I just have no clue how to stop it:

```
def get_neighbors(grid):
    neighbors = {}

    for row in grid:
        for col in row:
            directions = [(grid.index(row) + 1, row.index(col)), (grid.index(row) - 1,row.index(col)), (grid.index(row), row.index(col) - 1), (grid.index(row), row.index(col) + 1)]
            neighbors[row.index(col)] = [directions[0], directions[1], directions[2], directions[3]]
    return neighbors
```

I know there are better ways of implementing what I try to do which is take a node in a matrix and assign a key to that node and its values are the nodes up, down, left and right at that point in the matrix, so if someone can suggest a better way and write I would appreciate it a lot.

My problem with this implementation was that it outputs the below(I will give only a few examples not the whole output because it is too much):

```
{0: [(20, 0), (18, 0), (19, -1), (19, 1)], 1: [(20, 1), (18, 1), (19, 0), (19, 2)], 2: [(20, 2), (18, 2), (19, 1), (19, 3)]..}
```

As you can see The row section in the (row, column) tuples is always 20 because this is the number of total rows in the grid so the problem is that it outputs the index of a row that is only in the last iteration
How can I make my output look like this:

```
{0: [(1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)], 1: [(2, 1), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2)], 2: [(3, 2), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3)]
```

So basically make the row work the same way as the columns do in this particular example

Comment: What does `grid.index()` do?

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get a tuple with the index of an element and the element as you iterate through the grid:

```py
def get_neighbors(grid):
    neighbors = {}
    for j, row in enumerate(grid):
        for i, col in enumerate(row):
            neighbors[len(neighbors)] = [(i+1, j), (i-1, j), (i, j-1), (i, j+1)]
    return neighbors
```